# Get identity Id from xml batch insert in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, openxml

```xml
<Array><obj><id>1</id><name>name1</name></obj><obj><id>2</id><name>name2</name></obj></Array>
```

suppose I have an xml like the above

I want to insert it into a table say 'tablexml'

my code is like this

```
INSERT INTO tableXml
            (
            ,name
            
            )
        SELECT
            
            ,name 
     

        FROM OPENXML(@docHandle,'/Array/obj',2)  
     WITH(
         name varchar         'name'  
         
   )
```

This is inserting the array in xml to the table `tableXml` correctly with auto-increment pk,
But what i want is
I want to insert the id in xml,
id inserted to table `tableXml` as PK into another table inside the loop

I searched a lot for this but coudn't find an answer, i could only get the last record

Please help

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the old `OPENXML` function as it has many issues.

Instead, use the newer XQuery syntax

```sql
INSERT tableXml (id, name)
SELECT
  x.obj.value('(id/text())[1]','int'),
  x.obj.value('(name/text())[1]','varchar(100)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/Array/obj') x(obj);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8bc8ba264299408927f5639337c27de4)